# ffmpeg- using ffmpeg to take an image from camera and store it

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, date-time

The below file does most of what I want quite well.  However, the time format seems not quite what I want. I would prefer to always get time in `ISO8601` (e.g. 20150930T012823Z) regardless of the time setting on computer. How can that be done?

```
@ECHO off
:: Check the Windows version
IF NOT "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" GOTO:OS
SETLOCAL

:: Initialize variable
SET Error=0

:: Check the command line arguments
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO Syntax
IF "%~2"=="" GOTO Syntax
IF "%~3"=="" GOTO Syntax

set v_barrier=%1
set v_rtspcommand=%2
set v_AccessCard=%3
set v_Pictures=%4
IF "%~4" =="" set v_Pictures=%PUBLIC%\Pictures

:: Keep variables local
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Checking if ffmpeg is properly installed as per setting in PATH
IF NOT EXIST "%ffmpeg%\ffmpeg.exe" (
  ECHO ffmpeg.exe could not be found in %ffmpeg%
  GOTO:EOF
)

VERIFY OTHER 2>nul
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Unable to enable extensions

if "%date%A" LSS "A" (set toks=1-3) else (set toks=2-4)
   for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%a in ('echo:^|date') do (
   for /f "tokens=%toks% delims=.-/ " %%i in ('date/t') do (
   set '%%a'=%%i
   set '%%b'=%%j
   set '%%c'=%%k))

if %'yy'% LSS 100 set 'yy'=20%'yy'%
set Today=%'yy'%-%'mm'%-%'dd'%
ENDLOCAL & SET v_year=%'yy'%& SET v_month=%'mm'%& SET v_day=%'dd'%& SET /a last_year=%'yy'%-1

:: Time in ISO 8601 24-hour format
VERIFY OTHER 2>nul
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Unable to enable extensions
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:,.-/ " %%i in ('echo %time%') do (
  set 'hh'=%%i
  set 'mm'=%%j
  set 'ss'=%%k
  set 'ff'=%%l)
ENDLOCAL & SET v_hour=%'hh'%& SET v_minute=%'mm'%& SET v_second=%'ss'%& SET v_fraction=%'ff'%

:: Barrier = I1-I9 (for Ingress) or E1-E9 (for Egress)
set output_path=%v_Pictures%\%v_barrier%%v_year%%v_month%
if not exist %output_path% mkdir %output_path%

:: Delete folder that is one year old
if exist %v_Pictures%\%v_barrier%%last_year%%v_month% rmdir /s /q %v_Pictures%\%v_barrier%%last_year%%v_month%

:: Ingress / Egress parrier:
IF %v_barrier% GEQ I0 IF %v_barrier% LEQ I99 GOTO:NEXT
IF %v_barrier% GEQ E0 IF %v_barrier% LEQ E99 GOTO:NEXT
GOTO:SYNTAX

:NEXT
set timestring=%v_barrier%%v_year%%v_month%%V_Day%T%v_hour%""%v_minute%%v_second%Z%v_AccessCard%

START "" "%ffmpeg%\ffmpeg" -rtsp_transport tcp -y -i %v_rtspcommand% -nostats -loglevel 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f image2 -

vframes 1 -ss 00:00:01.500 -s 1920x1200 %output_path%\%timestring%.jpg
GOTO:EOF

:SYNTAX
ECHO FFMPEGPIS.BAT - FFMPEG Photo Imaging System ver 1.1
ECHO Usage:  FFMPEGPIS         [ Ix or Ex, rtsp, Access Card, Picture folder ]
ECHO.
ECHO Where:  "Ix or Ex"        I = Ingress followed by integer 0-9
ECHO                           E = Egress followed by integer 0-9
ECHO.
ECHO         "rtsp"            command from camera (rtsp)
ECHO         "Access Card"     Short Range Access Card
ECHO         "Picture Folder"  If blank, %PUBLIC%\Pictures will be used
:OS
IF NOT "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" ECHO         OS needs to be Windows NT 4 or higher
:EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an region-independent to get date and time.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (
  `wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`
) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j

set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%
echo Local date is [%ldt%]
```

output:

```
Local date is [2015-10-02 20:10:00.000]
```

Just edit the variable to your needs. You can get more variation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203116)